# Timestamping in Gstreamer pipeline

Tags: c, timestamp, gstreamer

I have created a gstreamer pipeline with my appsrc;
the pipeline is like this

```
appsrc name=src ! video/x-h264 ! decodebin ! queue ! autovideosink
```

I have written code to run this pipeline;
I will get h264 frames in my appsrc, and I am pushing it to decodebin. I am not receiving any timestamps in my appsrc. So I am thinking of feeding timestamps values (such that the fps will be 30fps). 
There are two feilds in the GstBuffer Structure, the `timestamp` feild and the `PTS` feild,
which one should I set with my timestamp. And on reference to which clock the render and decoder will check these timestamps ?

Currently wht I am doing is creating a baseclock reference from system time, and with respect to that time I am incrementing my timestamps, and it is not working, If I set only the duration feild it plays fine, But I want to implement the timestamp logic so that the decoder can drop some frames if some comes late.. I have very little knowledge about timestamping, so I want to know more about timestamping

Comment: Hi sir! Did you solve the problem? I also have the same error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using GST 1.0or GST 0.10?
There is no "timestamp" that is exposed in GST 1.0, whereas in 0.10 there aren't PTS/DTS.

Comment: I am using GST 1.0 ,and for the GstBuffer Structure, they have provided MACROS like GST_BUFFER_TIMESTAMP() ,GST_BUFFER_PTS() ,GST_BUFFER_DTS() etc,,, I want to pass my timestamp using these varibles